# most secure login management framework

Tags: authentication, security

I am using KeePass right now

I would like the most secure login managent framework available

I have seen that keeper plus yubikey bio creates perhaps the perfect solution, however yubikeys are expensive.

Is there an open source inexpensive solution, that utilises local USB storage, FIDO2, phone fingerprint or eye scan as part of the solution?

Comment: This is a highly subjective question, and not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope we're able to help with programming questions in the future.

Comment: Do what you want. Human will always be the weakest link in all the technologies and tooling. :)